HttpClient - Task canceled
I am trying to replace some older code to use HttpClient. I suspect that I am missing something basic. Using examples I have the code working when requesting from one URL and from another I get Task Canceled.
The only difference is the URL. Can someone point me int he right direction?
I have spent over a day on this, and the below code is the current try, I have done through many different things, in all I have the same issue of data not being returned.
The URLs themselves return data when pasted into Chrome browser, so they are valid.
' Does not work  (task canceled)  
Private Async Sub Button25_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button25.Click        
    Dim strContent As String = Await GetRequest("https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/historical-results-service/QLD/racing/2024-04-22/B/R/races/2")           
End Sub
    
' Works    
Private Async Sub Button25_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button25.Click      
    Dim strContent As String = Await GetRequest("https://www.tab.com.au/racing/meetings/today/R")      
End Sub

Async Function GetRequest(url As String) As Task(Of String)         
    Using client As New HttpClient()
        Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(url)      
            Using content As HttpContent = response.Content
                Dim myContent As String = Await content.ReadAsStringAsync()    
                Return myContent      
            End Using        
        End Using       
    End Using      
End Function


Does this answer your question? HttpClient - A task was cancelled?

Im not executing these as multiples, simply as single request. The Button25 subs are there to illustrate the difference

Nevertheless, declare the HttpClient instance as class member and dispose of it in the FormClosed event.

appreciate the advice, the code is just a testing snippet
